# Selling copy of GPL v3 app under another license

Tags: licensing, gpl, lgpl, proprietary-code, gnu

I want to create a library, that can be used for free in any open-source project, so I want to publish it under terms of GNU GPL v3. But, also I want to sell it, so it could be used in proprietary projects under terms of Lesser GPL or my proprietary license. Does GPL let me do this? If not, which copyleft license could I use?

Thank you!

Comment: As long as you're the sole copyright owner you are not bound by any license

Comment: Note: If you sell me an LGPLed code. I will publish it.This will then supersede the GPL.You should probably chose a different 2nd licence.

Comment: related https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9975/1084