# GPL - retaliation instead of restriction?

Tags: gpl

This question is inspired by the ongoing discussion about Red Hat restricting access to source code repositories.

We all know that you cannot restrict your customer's GPL rights by additional clauses or a separate contract. The question is whether it is legal to say: "If you ever use your GPL rights to publish the source code, we will terminate our contract with you and never offer you any services again."

Is this an open question to be determined by future court decisions?

Comment: I haven't looked closely but this may be a duplicate of [Threatening with non-renewal of contract when users distribute the GPLv2-licensed software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5426/50) (note it has divisive answers!)